# Не получается пробросить порты в контейнере

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Привет, не получается пробросить порт в контейнере, мучаюсь уже день, просто не понимаю. Запуска через команду 'docker-compose up -d'
Если ввести команду 'docker ps'

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4fea50856eef        docker_web          "python manage.py ru…"   13 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   docker_web_1
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /django.testsite/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN easy_install pip
RUN pip install django==1.9.12
RUN pip install requests

ADD . /.
WORKDIR /django.testsite

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Где я допускаю ошибку?

Comment: Так вроде все пробросилось. Чего конкретно не так?

Comment: проверьте firewall, версию docker-compose.

Comment: Я получаю такую вот ошибку: http://joxi.ru/Vm6oegWtxoQVK2 Не знаю почему.. На скрине другой адрес, так как експерементировал

Comment: Весрия docker-compose: (1.20.1)

Comment: Попробуйте указать:
expose: 5000
в Dockerfile.

Comment: `EXPOSE <port>` не используется так как `ports` свойство в `docker-compose.yml` установлено.

Comment: и что с firewall`ом у вас?

Comment: Отключен вообще

Comment: Попробуйте не отключать полностью службу firewalld, а перевести его в trusted (для свежих RPM-based дистрибутивов это можно сделать командой firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=trusted при запущенной службе firewalld)

Comment: можно попробовать `127.0.0.1:5000:5000`